# Limpar conteúdo do meu console netbeans em java

Tags: java, netbeans

Bom dia pessoal, qual comando eu utilizo em java para limpar o console do meu netbeans? Pois tenho um método que fica a cada x tempos imprimindo algumas mensagens e quero que fique limpando isso do meu console.

Answer (score 5):

Para limpar o console, você pode criar e executar o método abaixo, que identifica o SO e executa o comando adequado para limpar o console:

```
public final static void clearConsole(){

        try{
            final String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

            if (os.contains("Windows")){
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");

            }else{
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
            }
        }
        catch (final Exception e){
        //  Tratar Exceptions
        }
    }
```

**OBS.: Adaptação da resposta original publicada pelo usuário [Dyndrilliac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469257/dyndrilliac) em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console**

Answer (score -2):

```
/**
 * Função que limpa a Saída/Output do Netbeans
 */
public final static void limparSaida() {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.setAutoDelay(10);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: tente explicar sua resposta...

Answer (score -3):

Tente usar antes o comando `System.out.print ('\u000C');`

Comment: O que faz esse comando mais especificamente?